# Can you index a column that "changes" based its entries value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, in my database I have a table that has these two columns. I have a NoteType and a NoteTypeID. The not NoteType tells you what the noteTypeId is referencing. (this is an ID for another table so I can reference back to the entry from the note.) I have a query which I'd need to run a lot on this set of data and its very slow currently as notes are made for many situations. Is it possible for the noteTypeID to be indexed based on the noteType?
I am fairly new to the concept of indexing so I am unsure.

Comment: Show the table structure and the query you refer to.

Comment: A clustered index on NoteType, NoteTypeID seems to be what you are looking for. This would "group" (order) the index by NoteType then NoteTypeID. So if you are querying for NoteType values the engine could theoretically do an initial seek to the type of note, then return specific IDs. Without seeing your query or db structure all I can really say is make a copy of the table and test with indexes. SQL Sentry Plan Explorer is a free tool that's pretty solid for reading execution plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are frequently running queries like:

`SELECT NoteType FROM NoteInfo WHERE NoteTypeID=2900`, and each `NoteTypeID` is only associated with one `NoteType`, then an index *could* help search performance if your dataset is large.

Probably a [clustered index](https://www.giantstride.gr/sql-indexing-part2/) is the best way to go, if your data is structured this way. This helps the database locate the record for the appropriate `NoteType` for the passed in `NoteTypeID` in `O(log(n))` time -- way better than traversing the entire table.

Using either SQL Server Management Studio or T-SQL you can create an index. I could reproduce that info for you, but the stable link to the documentation (which is much better formatted than what I can reproduce here) is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes) from Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you very much! this was exactly what I was looking for!
edit: thanks for the extra reading btw I wanted to learn more on it!

Comment: Additional question, I already have a clustered index on this table. Is a non clustered acceptable too? Or will I have to settle for one or the other?

Comment: @MasonToy The table can only have one clustered index. The clustered index is effectively the table data itself. Like, it's the actual order the data in the table is sorted (I simplified, but that's the idea). So you can't have more than one. You can have multiple columns in the index, though.